# How can I set cookies in phonegap for windows phone?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, cordova, cookies

I want to store some data on server so that when I login again, server should remember me and retrieve my previous data.

As of now as I'm not using any session management when I login with some username and send some message and all, it shows me some response and when I login with another username its showing me the same data of that previous user.

So here is the problem of not maintaining session.

So please anyone tell me how can I maintain session with ajax JavaScript and jQuery.

I can't use any server side script as I'm working with visual studio express 2012 for windows phone.

So guide me for session management or information about cookie in phonegap app.

Comment: `when I login with another username its showing me the same data of that previous user.` How do you save the data? I would assume any data saved is associated to the current logged in user id so another user id should never see the that data. Can you post the relevant code you are using?

Comment: may be i have not maintained any session thats why its showing like this...let me explain suppose i m logging with some xy@gmail.com and did some operation like subscibe ,referral.when i login with another id ab@gmail.com its showing me the same opeartion which i performed for previous user.means if i m have not performed any opeartion in ab@gmail.com,then it should not show me that opeartion.it should be empty..but its not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.
for storing

```
localStorage.setItem("username", "Smith");
```

for getting

```
localStorage.getItem("username");// here returns smith
```

[ref](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

2 . second option use mobile database

[Refer this example](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Database)

3 . use cookies
[ref here for example of and plugins](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Database)

Comment: can we use like localStorage.setItem("username", "Smith"); in one page and getting this value in another page..is it possible..?

Comment: thanks..i have completed that ..but still i m not understanding about the session means i m facing one problem is when i am login with some id suppose xyz@gmail.com and has did some operation so browser doesnt recognise me ,means if i am logged with other id after that suppose abc@gmail.com then still its showing me same operation which i did using xyz@gmail.com.